# TikZ nodes' input and output anchors

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

Looking at the pgfmanual section 47.4.9 at the shape of the `make contact`... I'm having trouble understanding the point/use of the input- and output anchors.

The input and output anchors are placed exactly where the east and west anchors are, which means they are *not* where the line should enter or exit the contact. Evidently the shape is drawn correctly regardless:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \node [contact] (contact 1) at (0,0) {};
    \node [contact] (contact 2) at (0,2) {};
    \draw (contact 1) to [make contact] (contact 2)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do the input and output anchors have any use for this component? And exactly how does the `to` function determine where to place the shape?

Comment: Your path is vertical so the shape is rotated accordingly. And to path accepts `pos` argument so it acts like a regular node. See `mark connection node` decoration for a similar application

Comment: I get the part about the rotation; that was not my point. Sorry if I was unclear. My point is that the line from `contact 1` does not connect to the `make contact`s `input` anchor. Evidently that anchor is not part of the positioning, and I wonder why. Also I wonder what _is_ part of the positioning.

Comment: Input anchor and west anchor as far as I can see from the code is the same point. Both inherit from `rectangle` shape but I don't know why they bothered to redefine the `input` anchor. For positioning a contact with west anchor is pretty useless don't you think? Southwest anchor would be much appropriate

Comment: My point exactly. My question is, how does TikZ determine which anchor (if any) to use. Or does it do something completely different. I doubt it guesses...

Comment: Ah OK now I get it. No it doesn't guess (actually one thing I've learned over the years is that in TeX nothing is guessed). That is defined by the to path `[make contact]` and the style `circuit symbol size`

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. The relevant anchor that the `to` function uses is neither `input` nor `output` but the `anchorborder`, which is actually based on the `center` anchor.

The relevant sections of the **pgfmanual** is 102.5.3 for the description of `\anchorborder` and 97.5.3 for `\pgfpointborderrectangle`, which `\anchorborder` typically uses.

I guess I learned something. Thanks percusse for the comments. They pointed me in the right direction.